# Problem getting the Fiber Mesh addon to work

Tags: mesh, add-on

I am new to blender so please go easy on me if I'm being a bit stupid here.  I am trying to apply the Fiber Mesh (bounce fiber) addon to a mesh in Blender.  I have followed every step in a couple of different tutorials but nothing appears in my 3D viewport, and I just wondered if there was something obvious I'm doing wrong / not doing?  Here's what I've done:

Installed Addon (pretty confident this is fine)
Added a new mesh cube
Converted object to a Bounce Fiber object (under object properties panel -> bounce fibers)
Ticked the 'use selection' box (under object properties panel -> bounce fibers)
Changed the number of bounces to 600

At this point, I had hoped that when I hide the mesh (fiber_cube) in the scene collection I would see the curves underneath, but there is nothing there.  There are also no sub-branches of the fiber_cube object.

However, if I go into the 'blender file' under display mode, and click 'curves' I see a curve named 'cu_fiber_cube_000000'.  If I drag this into my 3D viewport, it creates a new object in my current layer but still nothing is visible.

A few other things:  I'm in Object Mode throughout, in Global View, and on the Layout tab.  I have tried it with the same results in Blender 2.8 and Blender 2.9.

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd be really grateful!

Rich

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Hi, I have added a link at the bottom of the original post.  I hope it works - please let me know if I haven't done it correctly!

Comment: ok, looks like it does not work in the newest blender version anymore... :(

Comment: Thanks Chris, do you know which is the latest version that it works in, and if it's possible to download this version anywhere?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know...i tried it with 3 version (the latest ones), none of them worked for me...

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this Chris - really appreciate your time.  I just found a mirror for the download of 2.80 and it worked, so hopefully if anybody else needs it this can be a work around!  Thanks again.

Comment: so i am happy for u that it works now!